# How to avoid POP-UP close on submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to add member by getting data in pop up page.
On clicking **add member** button a pop-up appears.
In **add member** form I am trying to add a new user,Which gets stored in database and the details are fetched and shown in **member detail** table which is present in same pop up.[image]

The problem I am facing here is,On clicking save button the form gets submitted and the pop-up gets closed.

**

```js
function menuopen1(menuid) {
   if(document.getElementById(menuid)){
     document.getElementById(menuid).style.display = "block";
   }
 }


 function menuclose1(menuid) {
   if(document.getElementById(menuid)){
     document.getElementById(menuid).style.display="none";
   }
 }
```

```css
.openmenu{
 position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 99999;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 display: none;
}

.field_4{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.humb{
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width: 100px;
 background: cyan;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row{
 background: lightcyan;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color:#fff;
}

#popup {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 position: absolute;
 color: #000;
 background-color: lightcyan;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -200px;
 margin-left: -400px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}


.close {
 font-size: 40px;
    float: right;
    display: table;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*color: #fff;*/
    color: red;
}


.u_record {
    width: 617px;
    height: 105px!important;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.user_details {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}


.u_header{
 width: 600px;
 border-bottom : 1px solid #e4e4e4;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: table;
}
.u_record{
 width: 617px;
 height: 150px!important;
 border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 overflow-y:scroll;

}
.u_row{
 min-width:150px; 
 display: table-cell;
}
.r_hd{
 text-align: center;
}
.r_hd,.r_filter{
 padding: 5px 0;
 width: 100%;
 color: #4285f4;
 border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
.r_filter{
 text-align: right;
 height: 30px;
}
.r_filter img{
 width: 25px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.r_name{
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 color: #000;
}
.r_name1{
 display: table;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 color: #000;
}
.r_name1 img{
 float: left;
 width: 20px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}


.user_details{
 width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.save_btn{
 margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field_4">

  <div id="menuopen0" onclick="menuopen1('open0')" class="humb">ADD MEMBER</div>

 
 </div>
 <div id="open0" class="openmenu">
  <div id="popup" class="row">MEMBER DETAILS
   <div class="close" onclick="menuclose1('open0')">X</div>

    <form action='' method='POST'  enctype='multipart/form-data'>

       <p>Data fetched to the below php code</p>
        <div class='u_record'>
        
    <div class='u_header'>
     <div class='u_row'>
       <div class='r_hd'>First Name</div>
     </div>
     <div class='u_row'>
      <div class='r_hd'>Email</div>
     </div>
           

    </div>
        </div>
        
  <!--<?php

   $sql="SELECT * FROM user_details";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   echo"<div class='u_record'>";
    echo"<div class='u_header'>";
     echo"<div class='u_row'>";
      echo"<div class='r_hd'>First Name</div>";
     echo"</div>";
     echo"<div class='u_row'>";
      echo"<div class='r_hd'>Email</div>";
     echo"</div>";

    echo"</div>";

             if($result->num_rows>0){
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                $first_name_db=$row['first_name'];
                 $email_address_db=$row['email_address'];

      echo"<div class='u_header'>";
       echo"<div class='u_row'>";
        echo"<div class='r_name'>".$first_name_db."</div>";
       echo"</div>";
       echo"<div class='u_row'>";
        echo"<div class='r_name'>".$email_address_db."</div>";
       echo"</div>";
      echo"</div>";
     }
    }


   echo"</div>";

  ?>-->


   <div class="user_details">
    <p>ADD MEMBER</p>
    <div class="field">
     First Name:
              <input type="text"  name="first_name" placeholder="first_name"   value="">
          </div>

         

          <div class="field">
     Email ID:
              <input type="text"  name="email_address" placeholder="email_address"   value="">
          </div>

         

          <div class="field">
            <input type="submit" class="save_btn" name="submit"  value="SAVE">
          </div>

   </div>
  </form>


  
  </div>
 </div>
```

**

But I want is,After adding member the  and the data has to fetched in member details page of same pop up page **Without closing the pop-up**

Only On clicking the close button in pop-up ,the pop-up page needs to be closed.

Comment: I've voting to close this as too broad. What you have isn't a popup, it is a modal, and it isn't closing, you are loading a new page it doesn't appear on. To do what you want to do you need to use Ajax. Based on your selection of tags, you appear to have identified that but made no effort to use it at all. Go and read an [introductory tutorial on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: @Quentin   Since I have tried using ajax only, I have mentioned it as ajax in selection of tags .The value gets inserted.But the data won't be fetched in the member details table.It will be fetched only after refreshing. My actual expectation is whether it is modal or pop-up no problem.On submitting either the modal or pop-up should not close.

Comment: "But the data won't be fetched in the member details table.It will be fetched only after refreshing" — Then something must be wrong with the code you wrote to update the previously loaded document … and you haven't shown us that either.